# Select every min(Date) from group of similar rows?

Tags: mysql

This is table `Posts` structure (there are other columns that aren't important to the question):

```
Verb | Object | Date
```

I'm grouping by Verb and then Object, to group all similar rows, this is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts GROUP BY Verb, Object
```

I need to know the date of the oldest row in each group. How can this be done?

Comment: `SELECT Verb, Object, min(Date) FROM Posts GROUP BY Verb, Object` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT  Verb, 
        Object, 
        MIN(date) OldestDate
FROM    Posts
GROUP BY    Verb, Object
```

Have a look at [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min)

Answer (score 0):

To get oldest dates in each group, then try this:

```
SELECT Verb, Object, MIN(`date`) AS min_date
FROM Posts
GROUP BY Verb, Object;
```

If you want to fetch records having oldest dates in each group, then try this:

Then restart the MySQL server.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Posts a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Verb, Object, MIN(`Date`) AS `Date`
                 FROM Posts
                 GROUP BY Verb, Object
                ) b
                ON a.Verb =  b.Verb
                   AND a.Object = b.Object
                   AND a.`Date` = b.`Date`;
```

Comment: Your second query need to include Verb and Object in the subquery and the join conditions. Otherwise, if Verb/Object A has a row whose date is the same as Verb/Object B's min date, that A row will be returned as well.